# Find the the distribution function of random variable Z and its expected value

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Point P is the midpoint of a line segment `AB` whose length is 1. Let point T1 be a  random point between points A and P, and point T2 be a random point between points A and B. The random variable Z is the length of the line segment `T1T2`. Find the distribution function of Z and its expected value.

My current progress:

I will define the length of line segment `AT1` as `X` and  `AT2` as `Y`. Which leads to `Z=|Y-X|`.

So there are 2 cases:

`1) X > Y`

```
2) Y > X
```

Now using graphs I find the limits of Z.

(I'd include a graph but im not allowed because the lack of reputation)

For the first case`(X > Y)` I get the limits of Z as `[0, 0.5]`, and for the second case`(Y > X)` I get the limits of Z as `[0.5, 1]`.

The funtion for the first case is `Y=X-Z`, and for the second is `Y=X+Z`

Now comes the part where I need to define the limits of the mariginal distribution which I am currently stuck on.

Comment: I have defined the limits of Z as you can see. I do not understand what do you mean about overthinking it. This is a problem with 2 uniformly distributed variables which absolute difference results in the said Z. Now inserting the right limits in the double integral (mariginal distribution) gives the distribution function that is needed. Those limits are what I am stuck on.

Comment: Oh, I misread your problem statement.  Sorry.